# Can data be kept in a dynamically bound GridView's invisible fields?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a query expression which I am binding to a GridView in Page_Load. The data I want to capture in the SelectedIndexChaned event is in a BoundField defined thus:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                            SortExpression="ID" Visible="False"  />
```

If I set Visible="True", I have no trouble getting this data. Is there a way to hide the ID field and still get the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how you are trying to get the data.  If this is an ID field that is unique for each row in the datasource, use `DataKeyNames = "ID"` in the GridView declaration.  Then, in the code behind, whenever you need the ID, you can use the following line:

```
string ID = GridView1.Rows[GridRowIndex].DataKeys[0].Value.ToString();
```

You could also convert one of your BoundFields to a TemplateField, and place a HiddenField in it to store the ID.  Like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="someOtherDataLabel" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="IDHiddenField" runat=server />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you could use `FindControl()` in the `RowDataBound` event of the GridView to store the ID value.

Comment: Your second way worked like a charm. Intellisense didn't agree with the first one. Thanks a million.