# GridView trouble in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i think this maybe an easy one...
I have a Gridview, bound to a dataSource with this query:
select userid, name, phone from users
I need to change the content of the Name cell to a link, like so:
`<a href="http://www.domain.com/page.aspx?userid=12345">User's Name</a>`
so OnRowDataBound i'm doing this:

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<a href=\"http://www.domain.com/page.aspx?userid=\" + e.Row.Cell[0].Text + "\">" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</a>";
```

It all works fine this way. My problem is that i don't want to display the UserId column in the Gridview, but when i attribute it (asp attribute or server-side) `Visible="false"` to the BoundField UserId, i can't capture it's value to build the Name Cell.

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your gridView to use template items instead of simple grivdiew column.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName"> 
  <EditItemTemplate> 
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>'>
      </asp:TextBox> 
      </EditItemTemplate> 
   <ItemTemplate> 
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'>
     </asp:Label> 
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can find a nice intro [Here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

Comment: ok i think this is the way to go, but i'm having big trouble, escaping a <a href=""> inside the Text attr of a label. i tried it in a million ways, can you help me out please?

Comment: Maybe calling Html.Encode could solve the issue in your code block.

Comment: Couldn't you add a hyperlink user control rather than the markup as a string. That way you wouldn't need to excape it

Comment: Lol, I'm sorry man, i am so tired i should have stopped coding a few hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jani, this should be done with a template field.  If you really need to do it the other way, see [Can data be kept in a dynamically bound GridView's invisible fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195852/can-data-be-kept-in-a-dynamically-bound-gridviews-invisible-fields).

Answer (score 0):

you can set the visibility on the onrowdatabound event